# How to make a simple HTML CSS Time diagram

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a time diagram which displays lab usage time using HTML CSS divs. I put something together, but it is not turning out as well as I thought.

```css
div {
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.alloted {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  height: 80px;
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.actual {
  opacity: 0.6;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  height: 60px;
  width: 65%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-top: 40px;
  position: absolute;
}

.bringUp {
  background-color: orange;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  width: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.idle {
  background-color: brown;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  width: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.lost {
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  width: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.used {
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  width: 55%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="actual">
  Actual Time Used
  <div class="bringUp">
    Bring Up
  </div>
  <div class="idle">
    Idle
  </div>
  <div class="lost">
    Lost
  </div>
  <div class="used">
    Used
  </div>
</div>
<div class="alloted">
  Alloted Lab Shot
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is creating a block of "actual" time which is made up of several blocks in line (Bringup, idle, lost, used). I also need to create another block which can move inside or outside of the actual time block to represent allotted time. The behavior is very similar to a stack bar chart, but not quite the same. The widths are hard coded in the CSS above, but the idea is the values would be based upon user input.

Any advice to achieve this would be great!

Comment: The behavior described is best handled by JavaScript/jQuery. Please add the script you have tried using but failed. BTW your HTML is only divs which leads me to believe that you'll need to at least know the fundamentals of HTML/CSS. If you wanted user input, you'd know that a button, textbox, etc would be be needed not a bunch of divs.

Comment: I don't have a script. I simple put together some html/css to prototype the idea more or less. I am very new to web design and this feature is pushing my capabilities. I already have a user form together so the data can be input by the user and js can pull the data. I am wondering if something similar to this has already been developed.

Comment: Load jQuery, jQuery-UI, and Bootstrap, then do research on drag n drop. If it's a bunch of divs that represent chunks of time that the user can arrange, drag n drop is a good UX (if done properly of course). Your question is too broad, this site deals in resolving code that has problems. You have not provided any code that looks close to the level you have described.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like that:

- Set margins that are inherited from the parent to 0
- Set heights manually is the easiest way in this case
- Place "Actual Time Used" in a absolute positioned span

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.alloted {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.actual {
  opacity: 0.6;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  height: 60px;
  width: 65%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-top: 40px;
  position: absolute;
}

.actual span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 50%;
}

.bringUp {
  margin: 0;
  height: 58px;

  background-color: orange;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  width: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.idle {
  margin: 0;
  height: 58px;

  background-color: brown;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  width: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.lost {
  margin: 0;
  height: 58px;

  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  width: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.used {
  margin: 0;
  height: 58px;

  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  width: 55%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="actual">
  <span>Actual Time Used</span>
  <div class="bringUp">
    Bring Up
  </div>
  <div class="idle">
    Idle
  </div>
  <div class="lost">
    Lost
  </div>
  <div class="used">
    Used
  </div>
</div>
<div class="alloted">
  Alloted Lab Shot
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this fix. Why is the transparency applied to all the DIVs? shouldn't it just be applied to the div with the "actual" class and just that one?

Comment: Some attributes are inherited from parent to child elements so you have to manually overwrite them in the child elements.